# Rails encoding url params from a helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I generate a url in a Rails helper it converts the querystring params from this:

```
?id=2&asdfsadf=2234324
```

into:

```
?id=2&amp;asdfsadf=2234324
```

I'm using this url to link to an image. Is this url still valid even though the ampersands have been replaced?

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- it's valid HTML. Your browser will decode the `&amp;` into `&`. (It's not valid for pasting into the address bar. Well, technically it is valid, but it won't do what you expect.)